# Overloading on inheritance with CRTP and other templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I've got a problem with overloading some operators.

Specifically, I have a template, `interface_mixin<T>`, which has the traditional CRTP setup, i.e., `Derived : public interface_mixin<Derived>`.

Now I need to overload operators on which side is an object, but the other side is a template, that is:

```
template<typename T, typename Derived> ... operator..
(T t, const interface_mixin<Derived>& d) {
    ... 
}
template<typename T, typename Derived> ... operator..
(const interface_mixin<T>& t, Derived d) {
    ... 
}
template<typename T, typename Derived> ... operator..
(const interface_mixin<T>& t, const interface_mixin<Derived>& d) {
    ... 
}
```

However, my compiler (VS2010) won't accept this, calling ambiguous overload. How can I convince it to accept these overloads?

Right now, I'm trying to use SFINAE to try to clear the other overloads. But even though the logic seems fine, the compiler picks the wrong overload.

```
template<typename T, typename Derived> 
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<
        interface_mixin<T>, 
        T
    >::value, 
    and<
        equality_rule<T>, 
        Derived
    >
>::type operator>>(T t, const interface_mixin<Derived>& d) {
    return and<equality_rule<T>, Derived>(equality_rule<T>(std::move(t)), d.crtp_cast());
}
template<typename T, typename Derived> 
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<
        interface_mixin<Derived>, 
        Derived
    >::value, 
    and<
        T, 
        equality_rule<Derived>
    >
>::type operator>>(const interface_mixin<T>& t, Derived d) {
    return and<T, equality_rule<Derived>>(t.crtp_cast(), equality_rule<Derived>(std::move(d)));
}
template<typename T, typename Derived> and<T, Derived> operator>>(const interface_mixin<T>& t, const interface_mixin<Derived>& d) {
    return and<T, Derived>(t.crtp_cast(), d.crtp_cast());
}
```

However, VS is picking the wrong overload, and the logic won't make sense when the wrong overload is picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question differs form second, you don't specify return type an function body there.
If return type is `void` - this code works with my MSVC2010 compiler:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct interface_mixin {};

template<typename T, typename Derived>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<interface_mixin<T>, T>::value, void>::type
operator>>(T t, const interface_mixin<Derived>& d) { std::cout << "1\n"; }

template<typename Derived, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<interface_mixin<T>, T>::value, void>::type
operator>>(const interface_mixin<Derived>& d, T t) { std::cout << "2\n"; }

template<typename DerivedL, typename DerivedR>
void
operator>>(const interface_mixin<DerivedL>& t, const interface_mixin<DerivedR>& d)
{ std::cout << "3\n"; }

struct Foo : interface_mixin<Foo> {};
struct Bar : interface_mixin<Bar> {};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;

    1 >> f;
    f >> 1;
    f >> b;
}
```

I don't know if the problem is with return type or something other, but `enable_if` should solve this problem.

Comment: The second part was my attempt to fix the problem presented in the first part. Strange, I also got the correct results compiling your code independently, and I don't see the difference between the second part and your answer.

Comment: @DeadMG, provide complete minimal code reproducing this issue.

Comment: I tried that. I copied and pasted my code and ran the three test cases, and it compiled just fine! But my actual use code doesn't work.

Comment: Turns out one of my classes didn't inherit properly! Thanks, your answer caused me to discover the error.

Comment: @DeadMG, like `Foo : interface_mixin<Bar>` ? Unfortunately we can't prevent this in VC++2010 :(